# Changing date format from 'yyyy-mm-dd' to 'yyyy MMM dd' or 'MMM dd, yyyy'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datetime-format

I have searched the site but haven't found an answer close to what I need. Basically my date is displayed correctly as "**2013-05-09**" but what I want is "**2013 March 19**" or to make it better "**March 19, 2013**".

Please provide me with links to where its been answered already if any.

Comment: What's a "JSON date"?

Comment: Have a look at this library: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean like this?

```
var monthStrings = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var yourDate = "2013-05-09";
var result = yourDate.split("-")[0] + " " + monthStrings[parseInt(yourDate.split("-")[1])] + " " + yourDate.split("-")[1];
alert(result);
```

I've looked for a predefined function in javascript that does this before, but when i searched, this was the simplest answer I got, and I use this too.

Comment: Thanks pythonian, much better

Comment: Sorry pythonian, it was reporting error with regards to Integer.parseInt, so I ended up using moment.js plugin. I will still prefer your method but i need to figure out the reason for error

Comment: ok, can you inspect element in chrome and give me the error? maybe I've seen it before

Comment: OK I will test this again when I am back from work. Thanks for following up. This is what SO is about

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` should just be `parseInt`

Comment: Oh! yes sorry my bad, I've been coding in php recently, mistook this with the java equivalent

Comment: Bravo and can confirm it works. Thanks for following up on this. Much appreciated.

Comment: nice! 28 more rep and I'm on a thousand yaaaaay! hahaha, sorry about that brainfart, I shoulda checked my code before just typing, I was in a taxi and answered it from my mobile